# Minimum number of elements after removing directly connected components

Tags: algorithm

Say I have a undirected represented by an adjacency matrix:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 0]]
```

`a[i][j] = 1` if nodes `i` and `j` are connected. One operation consists of removing any two directly connected components from the graph. For example in the above graph you can remove nodes 0 and 1. What is the minimum number of nodes remaining after any number of operations?

Obviously we can do this in `O(N^2 * 2^N)` by brute forcing every single combination of components. I'm thinking there is a greedy method that can solve this in `O(N)` or `O(N^2)`.

Edit:

Two nodes are directly connected if `A[i][j] = 1`. This isn't transitive, so if `(i, j)` are directly connected and `(j, k)` are directly connected, `(i, k)` are not neccesarily directly connected.

Comment: Is "directly connected component" a concept (different from connected component)? If so, what is its definition?

Comment: The problem statement is not clear to me. Are you using the term `connected component` in its usual meaning? Because in that case, what would `two directly connected components` mean? Also is your intention to find an optimal algorithm to calculate the remaining number for a given input? In that case is `N` the dimension or the number of entries of the matrix or what?

Comment: my bad, see edit

Comment: In the edit you define the adjective "directly connected" for nodes, but this adjective is used in the question for "components". What are you calling components? Nodes?

Comment: This sounds like a maximum matching, which can be found with [Edmonds' algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nico Schelter wrote, what do you want to find is a [maximum matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)).

[image]

You can use [blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) for this.